# Convert arrow object in a Pandas dataframe to datetime64[ns]

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am having issues with converting an arrow date type inside a pandas dataframe to datetime64[ns] and all the solutions I have tried has not worked for me.

I use Python 3.10.6

This is an example of the code I have issue with:

```
            test = arrow.utcnow() 
            df = pd.DataFrame({"test": [test]})
            df.at[0,"test"] = df.at[0,"test"].datetime # How do I convert to datetime64[ns]?
            print(df.dtypes) # Prints 'object'
```

The arrow type is an 'object' before the conversion-attempt, and remains an 'object' afterwards when I want something like 'datetime64[ns]

From what i understand arrow has not been particularly compatible with pandas historically, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no other option than accessing [`Arrow.datetime`](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-guide.html#arrow.arrow.Arrow.datetime) attribute passed to `pd.to_datetime`:

```
pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(arrow.utcnow().datetime))
```

---

```
0   2023-10-06 12:33:54.395394+00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, tzutc()]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I understand it my mistake was trying to convert after the dataframe is created. I tested you solution like this and it worked:

`
test = arrow.utcnow() 
df = pd.DataFrame({"test": [pd.to_datetime(test.datetime)]})
print(df.dtypes) # Prints 'datetime64[ns, tzutc()]'
`